# Youtube Api Explorer InvideoPromotion Throws Access Forbidden

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to use the Youtube API explorer to set up a In-Video Promotion across my channel as a proof of concept before I write it into a webapp. I'm working off the java example for adding a featured video from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#add_a_featured_video. I can't get around this error code:

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.common",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "body.invideoPromotion.item.websiteUrl"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized."
 }
```

Here's my request:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=invideoPromotion&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "invideoPromotion": {
  "defaultTiming": {
   "type": "offsetFromStart",
   "offsetMs": "15001"
  },
  "items": [
   {
    "customMessage": "test message",
    "id": {
     "websiteUrl": "https://google.com",
     "type": "website"
    }
   }
  ],
  "useSmartTiming": true
 },
 "id": "<channel id recieved from earlier request in the java example>"
}
```

I am authorizing requests with Oauth2 with all the available youtube scopes selected. The error code seems to suggest there are more scopes specific to the update channel operation but all I can find in the documentation are the 6 general youtube scopes.

Comment: I think I know know the issue you are encountering. You are using the "YouTube For Developers." channel, which you don't have any update function or role to do so. Try using your own channel and test if you will still encounter that issue.

Comment: I wasn't, I just didn't want to link everyone here to my channel, but I might try making a fresh one anyway

Comment: Check your api key.